# MobileFirst AppCenter: Error while calling an adapter from iphone on login

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-appcenter

I need to customize the **login step** of the MobileFirst AppCenter in order to make a call to an **external service** that creates the user in the DB if it doesn't exists, before performing the out-of-the-box login with the user provided.

In order to do this, I created and deployed an **adapter** that makes the call to the db, and in the AppCenter project, and I modified the code in the script `/common/js/appcenter/views/Login.js` (which is the script that actually performs the login), to include a call to the aforecited adapter, using the default method:

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,options)
```

Building and running the app on **Android**, it works fine, the call to the adapter works like a charm and it creates the user and then performs the log in.

However, building and running on **IOS**, i stumble on the following error when trying to call the adapter through the `invokeProcedure` method:

```
Method 'getWlSignedClientId:' not defined in Plugin 'WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'
```

The `WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin` is defined in the iphone config.xml in this way (i was getting a plugin missing before first):

```
 <feature name="WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin">
     <param name="ios-package" value="WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin"/>
 </feature>
```

The error seems to be in the default plugin `WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin` defined in worklight.js, which I have no control on, and it basically prevents me from using the invokeProcedure method (however it works on Android).

Any help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what version and build of MobileFirst are you using. I suggest that you will attempt again by downloading the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central, and use the new/fresh project for the AppCenter Installer app, and try again. The App is a regular Hybrid app that that you need to build in MobileFirst Studio, so ensure you are using an up-to-date build of it as well. This is where the SDK is then added to the project and should contain the mentioned "missing" plug-in.